# R: How to remove the sub table that have duplicates in one column?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

Suppose that we are given a data table/frame in R:

```
  ID_number       Name
   001            Adam
   002            Adam
   003            Sam
   004            Nike
   005            James
   006            James
```

How can I remove the rows that have duplicate IDs or just take the rows that have unique IDs? In this case, we should get the sub table:

```
  ID_number       Name
   003            Sam
   004            Nike
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the duplicated rows with `duplicated`

```
df1[!(duplicated(df1$Name)|duplicated(df1$Name, fromLast = TRUE)),]
```